# How can i insert Oracle Database to PhpMyAdmin if PhpMyAdmin Support MYSQL

Tags: oracle, phpmyadmin

I want to insert oracle db to live server (phpmyadmin). But the main problem is that phpmyadmin only supports mysql. So is there any way to upload oracle db to phpmyadmin.

I'm very new to databases

Comment: Why does it have to be phpmyadmin? What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I want to upload pl/sql database to server

Comment: If that something you can't do for example with [SQL Developer](https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/sqldev-v192-downloads.html)?